# Is it true that there is a continuous, onto map from $(0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Is it true that there is a continuous, onto map from $(0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$?

I am trying but could not approach.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried using tangent function. but that $1$ is giving some problem

Comment: I'm probably missing something but assume that $f : (0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and surjective. Then $f|_{(0,1)} : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}\setminus \{f(1)\}$ is also continuous and surjective. But $(0,1) $ is connected which then implies that $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{f(1)\}$ is connected as an image of a connected set via a continuous function. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @mechanodroid Well, your argument just shows that there must be $x\in(0,1)$ with $f(x)=f(1)$.

Comment: @MarsPlastic Right, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ maps $(0,1]$ to $[1,+\infty)$. Can you map the latter onto $\Bbb R$ continuously? Then compose.

Comment: Kudos to @HennoBrandsma for not just giving this student the answer to his homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Try $\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

One example is
$$ f(x) = \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x} $$